# Decode QR-Code in scanned PDF

Tags: decode, qr-code

I'm trying to decode qr-codes in a PDF (generate by Scan2Mail with a Canon iR Scanner).
I know the quality is quite poor (see attached image), but with every single **iOS** app for qr-code scanning I can **successfully scan** the code within milliseconds filming the image below with the iPhone cam.

I tried to scan with **zbarimg** and **zxing** but nothing did work. Do you have ideas what to do? maybe enhance the image somehow with imagemagick?

[image: qr code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems counter-intuitive that an image of an image decodes, when the original image doesn't. An app is seeing a stream of slightly different versions of the image. The original is damaged and distorted. The blur that results when the camera captures it can actually help remove the noise. Yes, zxing decodes this fine -- from the Barcode Scanner app.

Try running this through a light blur filter first.

Comment: thanks... that alone didn't help, but what did help additionally - and I don't know why - was to lett zxing scan the whole image and not just the cropped part with the code

Comment: It depends on what Binarizer you use, but one of them chooses the black/white threshold based on the whole image. Looking at the whole image may give you a different black point and a slightly different image. Try `CommandLineRunner` and `--dump_black_point` to see what it "sees" after binarization.