# Improve zbarimg qrcode recognition

Tags: qr-code

I had a working system of scanning sheets of paper and then letting zbarimg recognize qrcodes on these sheets (while I don't know in which area the qrcode appears). Suddenly qrcode recognition got much worse and eventually stopped working at all.

The physical scanner generates PDFs from the scanned sheets of paper. I use ghostscript to convert it to a picture:

`gs -sDEVICE=png16m -sCompression=lzw -r600x600  -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile='scantest.png' scantest.pdf`

This is the result:
[image: scanned page converted to png via ghostscript]

When you try to read the qrcode with your smartphone, it will be recognized immediately. But when I run zbarimg:

`zbarimg scantest.png`

Zbarimg doesn't recognize anything:

> scanned 0 barcode symbols from 1 images in 6,6 seconds

I tried to apply this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40609947/4654597

But without any luck, actually it destroyed the qrcode totally:

[image: scanned page after morphological closing]

I also tried to apply a light blur filter like suggested in this post:
[Decode QR-Code in scanned PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291967/decode-qr-code-in-scanned-pdf)

I used ImageMagick for this task:
`convert scantest.png -blur 1x1 scantest_after_blur.png`

I also tried 1x2, 1x3, 1x4, 1x6, 1x8 but nothing helped.

How could I get zbarimg to work again?

Comment: You have white dots in the black areas. You can remove them by some morphology. Try `convert scantest.png -morphology erode square:1 scantest_after_erode.png`

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you very much. Minutes before you posted your comment I found the solution in another post in which you contributed the crucial information. `convert input.png +repage -threshold 50% -morphology open square:1 output.png` did the trick so I kept this command in the end. Unfortunately I don't well understand what is the difference between -morphology open and -morphology erode and what -threshold and +repage do.

Comment: `@Benedikt` erode will thicken black, open will fill black without thickening. -threshold 50% makes your black full black. open and erode will work on grayscale images. Your image is nearly black/white if not that already. The -threshold forces it to be completely black/white

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what finally worked:

```
convert input.png +repage -threshold 50% -morphology open square:1 output.png
zbarimg output.png
```

Most important is probably applying morphology. I got the whole ImageMagick command from this post: [QR code detection with ZBar from console fails for valid QR codes (ZBarCam from camera detects them fine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831824/qr-code-detection-with-zbar-from-console-fails-for-valid-qr-codes-zbarcam-from)